# Is it possible to do pseudo inverse for matrix in math.js?

Tags: javascript, math.js

I have searched math.js documentation and could not find a way to do pseudo inverse of a non-invertible matrix. May I ask if it is possible to do it on math.js or anyway else? Thank you!

(Equivalent of pinv in matlab)

`const XtXInv = math.inv(math.multiply(Xt, X))`